# display different series data in single line of Stacked Bar using highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to display different series of data in straight line in Stacked Bar of Highcharts. I need to display data based on min and max values. Please suggest on this.

```
series: [
       { "name": 'Active', 
       "data": [{ "low": 1325808000000, "y": 1335808000000 },
                { "low": 1335808000000, "y": 1343652000000 }
               ]
       },
       { "name": 'New', 
       "data": [{ "low": 1335808000000, "y": 1351814400000 },
                { "low": 1343652000000, "y": 1348952000000 }
               ]
       }
       ]
```

Sample can be found in below link.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/SuhailBaig/8e08b387/3/
```

Comment: What you would like to achieve here? I am not sure what is the main goal of your chart. Could you post some drawing showing what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi Grzegorz,
please find below post for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

[Expected Stacked Bar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XajU0.png)

Hi Grzegorz, 
Thanks for your response. 
Above link will help in better understanding of my requirement.
For source code, review in below jsfiddle url.

http://jsfiddle.net/SuhailBaig/8e08b387/3/

Sample Code:

```
series: [
       { "name": 'Active', 
       "data": [{ "low": 1325808000000, "y": 1335808000000 },
                { "low": 1335808000000, "y": 1343652000000 }
               ]
       },
       { "name": 'New', 
       "data": [{ "low": 1335808000000, "y": 1351814400000 },
                { "low": 1343652000000, "y": 1348952000000 }
               ]
       }
       ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add StackLables to the yaxis , in your case it will be xaxis since you are using column chart,

```
 yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Stacked Bar'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/a433zgqL/)

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan, Thanks for the response. But my requirements are

1) Chart type: Stacked Bar
2) Y-Axis: Display country names. Eg: INDIA, America
3) X-Axis: Display Quarters with tickinterval of 3
4) For series I have min and max values. so while displaying the bar should start from min value. Eg: I have 2 series(New, Active). and their values for INDIA are "New": min-1, max-3 and for "Active": min-3, max-5 so the bar should starts with 1 instead of 0.